# Number of terms in expansion of $(1+x+y+z)^5$

Tags: combinatorics

Had the first term been a variable I would have proceeded by finding possible solutions of equation $a+b+c+d+e=5$, but the one in first variable may mean that certain solutions would be identical, I could not solve this problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_multinomial_coefficients

Comment: Binomial theorem... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem to be used for more variables. Previous comments is maybe more useful...

Comment: And doing the _simple_ work of expanding it, the result is $x^5+5 x^4 y+5 x^4 z+5 x^4+10 x^3 y^2+20 x^3 y z+20 x^3 y+10 x^3 z^2+20 x^3 z+10 x^3+10 x^2 y^3+30 x^2 y^2 z+30 x^2 y^2+30 x^2 y z^2+60 x^2 y z+30 x^2 y+10 x^2 z^3+30 x^2 z^2+30 x^2 z+10 x^2+5 x y^4+20 x y^3 z+20 x y^3+30 x y^2 z^2+60 x y^2 z+30 x y^2+20 x y z^3+60 x y z^2+60 x y z+20 x y+5 x z^4+20 x z^3+30 x z^2+20 x z+5 x+y^5+5 y^4 z+5 y^4+10 y^3 z^2+20 y^3 z+10 y^3+10 y^2 z^3+30 y^2 z^2+30 y^2 z+10 y^2+5 y z^4+20 y z^3+30 y z^2+20 y z+5 y+z^5+5 z^4+10 z^3+10 z^2+5 z+1$, so the result you are searcing is 56 (if I am not wrong)

Comment: Ok, now you corrected your answer. Before the power was 5. Now is 54. My previous comments does not apply anymore.

Comment: Evaluating $(w+x+y+z)^5$ at $w=1$ doesn't change the number of terms, since the $a$ in $w^ax^by^cz^d$ is determined by $b,c,d$ (from $a+b+c+d=5$). | Hey Yiorgos S. Smyrlis and freak_warrior, you can't just change the numbers in a problem because you say so. Rolling back.

Comment: @freak_warrior and YiorgosS.Smyrlis: Editing is good, modifying the math content is bad. Please be more careful.

Comment: By the way. Some research done :-) When the power is $54$ and we have $4$ terms (as stated below) the result is 1463 terms ;-) Someone care to list them all? Just kidding...

Answer (score 3):

If the first term had been a variable you would have been looking at $(w+x+y+z)^5$, i.e. at terms of the form $w^ax^by^cz^d$ where $a+b+c+d=5$ with $a,b,c,d$ non-negative integers (note, no $e$).

Instead you are looking at terms of the form $x^by^cz^d$ where  $b+c+d \le 5$ with $b,c,d$ non-negative integers.  But this has exactly the same number of solutions ${5+4-1 \choose 5}=56$: any solution to the former clearly gives a solution to the latter, and any solution to the latter gives a solution to the former with $a=5-b-c-d$.

Comment: It is still $5$ objects into $4$ bins, one bin happens to be where the exponent of $1$ goes. Using the "stars and bars" method,
$$
\underbrace{\star}_{\text{exponent of $1$}}|\underbrace{\star\star}_{\text{exponent of $x$}}|\underbrace{\star}_{\text{exponent of $y$}}|\underbrace{\star}_{\text{exponent of $z$}}
$$
is $\binom{5+4-1}{5}$.